# Dynamic programming for optimal change

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I'm writing a program that will give an optimal way of getting the right change for a given set of denominations. For example, if the user enters the denominations "10,50 60", the output will be "1-10 cent coin, 1-50 cent coin for 60 cents". This is the code I've written so far, but there's still some debugging to do.

In terms of defining the variables, the amount is the change that needs to be solved for, and the denominations is the "tally" of different integers that make up a coin currency.

I'm running across a number of errors when attempting to compile, such as the returns of sum and previous, the if statement asking whether the total number of denominations in the sum tally is less than or equal to the one in previous, and 'identifier expected' errors in the parameters of the method.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
public static Tally makeOptimalChange(int[] denominations, int amount,       
    Tally currentAmount, int sum.length, int previous.length) {

  int sum = 0;

  Tally[][]tallyTable = new Tally[denominations.length][amount + 1];
  Tally previous = new Tally(denominations.length - 1);
  Tally difference = new Tally(denominations - row);
  for (int i = 0; i < denominations.length; i++) {
      tallyTable[i][0] = new Tally(denominations.length);

      if (amount >= denominations[index]) {

        Tally oneCoin = new Tally(denominations.length);
        oneCoin.setElement(whichCoin, 1);

        for (int j = 0; j < denominations.length(); j++) {
            sum = getElement(difference) + getElement(oneCoin);
        }
        return sum;

      } else {
        return previous;

    }

    if (sum.length() <= previous.length()) {
      return sum;
    }

    else {
      return previous;
    }

  }

    return Tally.IMPOSSIBLE;
}
```

Comment: You can't name your parameters given to the method `sum.length`, this is not allowed. Change them to `sumLength` or some other name. Same for `previous.length`.

Comment: your these two method parameters are wrong `int sum.length, int previous.length`. please specify correct parameter. ans also you are using `sum and previous` so i think these parameters should be replaced by `sum and previous`

Comment: That seemed to take care of that particular error. Would I have to specify somewhere that those two parameters are their respective lengths of each tally?

Comment: No, just pass the length to the method like `makeOptimalChange(denominations, amount,       
    currentAmount,  sum.length, previous.length)`

Comment: your Return type is `Tally` but you are returning an integer also